# I want to find the largest negative number out of a random range from -10 to 10 and the largest number will be squared from that range

Tags: python, loops

I want to find the largest negative number out of a random range from -10 to 10 and the largest number will be squared from that range that will be inputted by a person. for example lets say we have numbers like ***-7, -4, -2, 1, 3, 5, 8*** so the largest negative value in here is -2 , I would like that number to be squared as in MAXI(x) ** 2 and the largest negative value to be squared and then written in a new range of the values, but not sure how to use **MAXI** in a loop and to find the largest negative value.

```
    import random

print("Enter number of elements:")
n = int(input())

nums = []

for i in range(n):
    nums.append(random.randint(-10, 10))
    neg = [n for n in nums if n < 0]
    return [max(neg) if neg else 0]

for i in range(n):
    if
```

Comment: I'm not getting what 'then written in a new range of the values' means here. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you have problems finding the max negative value or the following task (whatever that is)?

Comment: `return` is invalid outside of a function, and that line and the one above should be de-indented so not to be in the for loop. But the code basically works `max(neg) if neg else 0` will give the right value (don't wrap it in `[...]` though)

Comment: @Elliveny I mean that I would input the ranges manually not randomly and after that the largest negative number gets squared. after the number gets squared the new range containing the modified negative number is written in a new range thats all the answer was correct i will just change the random radiant to input()

Comment: @Matthias my problem was that I was unable to somehow place the max inside the loop, I was just lost but the answer explained it, thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much code in the loop.

```
import random

n = 10

numbers = [random.randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(n)]
try:
    max_negative = max(number for number in numbers if number < 0)
except ValueError:  # there might be no negative value
    max_negative = 0

print(f'numbers: {numbers}')
print(f'square of max negative: {max_negative ** 2}')
```